# How to develop Chrome extension to check web sites periodically?

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-extension

I would like to make a small application to check special offers on some web site. This application should access this site periodically (once every few hours), parse the HTML to find the offer and notify me about the offer somehow.

I would like to develop it in JavaScript as a Chrome extension. Do you know about any examples of such an extension I can learn from?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome extensions have the features available that you're after:

- Request permission to the website you want to fetch.
- Make a [background page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) with a `setInterval` that makes an ajax request to the website and checks the contents.
- Use [notifications](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html) to notify the user of an update. After notifying, store the contents locally so you know when the live contents have been updated again.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of making an extension, would it not be better to just subscribe to a particular website's RSS feed? You can download a nifty extension called [RSS Live Links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-live-links/hcamnijgggppihioleoenjmlnakejdph) to give you updates, and you can subscribe to their offers feed.

Comment: One of my goals is to learn about `javascript` and chrome. Thanks for the `RSS Live Links` anyway.

Comment: @Michael: If you wanted to do that, I would suggest that you head over to YouTube and search "JavaScript TheNewBoston", that dude has some wonderful tutorials for JavaScript. And before you make extensions, it would better to make actual web pages that use JavaScript, then you can head over to extensions (since you want to learn that is).

Comment: I am making actual web pages with jquery etc. So I would like to try something else :)